# fixing animation between two activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to show a particular animation when the user goes from Activity A to Activity B. Right now, the default animation is being shown which i want to override. I want the new activity to swipe in from the right hand side. I am guessing that this can be achieved through     `overridePendingTransition()`

But do I have to create a new xml file for the animation I want to achieve or is there an existing one? How do I achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many animations on this page:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/

You can use it with overridePendingTransition().

Hope this helps :)